# How to redirect from ?page_id=... (apache)?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I have website at Wordpress. And it is webpage in Wordpress **www.my-domain/?page_id=111**

Now I need to create page outside of Wordpress (at the same server) and direct traffic to it instead of ?page_id=111.

When I create some rule in .htaccess `Redirect new_file.php https://www.my-domain/?page_id=111` nothing happen.

Thank you for every advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your parameters reversed.  It should be:
`Redirect old.html new.html`

However, Redirect won't handle a query string.  Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=111
RewriteRule oldpage.php newpage.php
```

Comment: hm.. nothing has changed. Would  I need to restart apache?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart Apache if it's in an .htaccess file, but you will if it's in the httpd.conf file or the httpd.conf.directory.  Are you sure your server has mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Yes, You are right. It was turn offed.